# parse error in eval() - eval()'d code

Tags: php

Where is the problem in my eval code???
because Apache said:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_STRING in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\1php\mas_res\inc\mysql_class.php(120)
>   : eval()'d code on line 1

my code:

```
            $type1 = "row";
            $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
            $textToEval = "mysql_fetch_{$type1}($query1);";
            $query = eval($textToEval);
```

And what is the correct mode??

Thanks ..

Comment: echo out your `$textToEval`, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Don't use eval!** Use PHP's [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php):

```
$function = 'mysql_fetch_' . $type1;
$query = $function($query1);
```

Oh, and if you want to know, what was the fault: You forgot to escape the `$` in `$query1`. It should be `\$query1`.

Comment: eval() is evil(), remember that! :)